# Are the following embeddings of the graph $K_{5}$ in the Möbius strip correct?

Tags: graph-theory, mobius-band

Are the following embeddings of $K_{5}$ in the Möbius strip correct?
If not could you help me understand why?

[image]

Comment: I previously doubted the second one. But on looking closer, both look correct (to me).

Comment: @coffeemath I still doubt the second one, because it looks like two edges intersect. What made you stop doubting it?

Comment: @MishaLavrov You are right--- I see the two edges joining 1 to 3 and 2 to 5 intersect. Also the edge 1 to 3 crosses the edge joining 2 to 4.

Comment: yes but for the second embedding could you not move vertex 2 down into (1,3,4,5) to eliminate crossings?

Comment: however, it looks like that would then be isomorphic to the first solution